# shell show args from the first to the one before the last

Tags: shell

I kwon how to show all the args and the last arg, but I need to know how to show all the args except the last,

```
$ bash show.sh a.txt b.txt c.txt ~/dest
a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
echo ${*:1:$(($#-1))}
```

This will grab all arguments, starting at the first index ( ignoring the script name ) and print until the second to last index.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `bash`, this is one way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq $(($#-1)) -1 1) ; do
    echo ${BASH_ARGV[$i]}
done
```

`BASH_ARGV` is a array containing the stack of the parameters, and you use `seq` to get the desired indexes into that array (in reverse order due to the stack-nature).

The `$#` is the number of parameters. Transcript follows:

```
pax> ./show.sh a.txt b.txt c.txt ~/dest
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```